# Kotlin discord jda cannot get message by id

Tags: kotlin, discord, discord-jda

I am trying to get the message by entering the id of the message. I saw this being done in an example but it used the old discordjda, when I tried now I get this wierd error and i dont know how to solve it. I tried casting it to different values with no succes

```
e.channel.history.getMessageById(userMessageFunction.b) {
    m ->
    if (e.message.timeCreated.isAfter(m.creationTime)) {
        userMessageFunction.c.accept(e.message)
        messageInteractivesQueue.remove(interactive)
    }
}
```

This is the error [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, that brace after `userMessageFunction.b` is considered
as lambda expression, so your code is same as this code.

```kotlin
e.channel.history.getMessageById(userMessageFunction.b, m -> {
    if (e.message.timeCreated.isAfter(m.creationTime)) {
        userMessageFunction.c.accept(e.message)
        messageInteractivesQueue.remove(interactive)
    }
})
```

If you want to get message, use `channel#retrieveMessageById`.
So you can change your code like this.

```kotlin
e.channel.retrieveMessageById(userMessageFunction.b).queue {
    if (e.message.timeCreated.isAfter(it.creationTime)) {
        userMessageFunction.c.accept(e.message)
        messageInteractivesQueue.remove(interactive)
    }
}
```

Or this

```kotlin
e.channel.history.getMessageById(userMessageFunction.b).let {
    if (e.message.timeCreated.isAfter(it.creationTime)) {
        userMessageFunction.c.accept(e.message)
        messageInteractivesQueue.remove(interactive)
    }
}
```